# Xamarin.Android: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, xamarin.android, jnienv

I am getting the following error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast(Android.Runtime.IJavaObject)' and 'Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast(Android.Runtime.IJavaObject)'

With this code:

```
// Get a pointer to the Java class.
IntPtr jClass = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/companyname/appname/JniClass");

// constructor.
IntPtr defaultConstructor = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(jClass,
                                               "<init>",
                                               "()V");
// new instance of the class.
IntPtr instance = JNIEnv.NewObject(jClass, defaultConstructor);

// Find method.
IntPtr methodID = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(jClass,   "getResult",    "()Ljava/lang/String;");

// Call the method.
IntPtr resultPtr = JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(instance, methodID);

// Convert the pointer to return value
Java.Lang.Object jObject = new Java.Lang.Object(resultPtr, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
Java.Lang.String result = jObject.JavaCast<Java.Lang.String>(); // Compiler Error
```

I'm curious as to why the compiler thinks that this code is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just for those who are still getting the same error!

In my case i removed the reference to namespace

```
Android.Runtime
```

might be in your case

```
Android.Runtime.Extension
```

might help someone!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have two methods with the same name but in different classes and Visual Studio needs to know which one you want to use.

Mouse over the error on the code and click on the 'light' icon and choose the method you want to use. You can also left click on the error onde the code and then press (ctrl + . (dot)) and choose the method you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have 2 extension methods of IJavaObject into 2 different namespaces. So I can call only `Namespace.ClassName.MethodName(parameter)` instead of `variable.MethodName().` But that just beats the whole idea of using extension methods.